# browser re-size issue slider out of conatiner

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

when i re-size the browser window the slider goes out of the main container
i am using bootstrap responsive css
i see the extra margin in the slider container if i remove its ok
but if i still make the window smaller slider goes out
how to fix the bug...

http://jsfiddle.net/48y2Q/embedded/result/
http://jsfiddle.net/48y2Q/

providing my code below

```
<div class="container">

                                <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 300px; background-position: 2700% 0%;">
                                  <div class="da-slide da-slide-fromright da-slide-current" style="width: 1122px;">
                                    <h2><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate1A.jpg" alt="image01"></h2>
                                    <div class="da-img"><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate1B.jpg" alt="image01"></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="da-slide da-slide-toleft" style="width: 1122px;">
                                    <h2><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate2A.jpg" alt="image01"></h2>
                                    <div class="da-img"><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate2B.jpg" alt="image01"></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="da-slide da-slide-toleft" style="width: 1122px;">
                                    <h2><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate3A.jpg" alt="image01"></h2>
                                    <div class="da-img"><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate3B.jpg" alt="image01"></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <nav class="da-arrows" style="width: 1122px;">
                                    <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                                    <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
                                  </nav>
                                <nav class="da-dots"><span class="da-dots-current"></span><span class=""></span><span class=""></span></nav></div>
                                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have fixed width in many places, so it won't fit mobile layouts. Change it: every place where you have `style="width: ****px"` make it `style="width: 100%"`.

I've tried it, looks pretty good: http://jsfiddle.net/48y2Q/1/

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you tell me how % is better than px

Comment: @user1943618 It's not better, it's different. :) 100% means full available width (and no more), so slider will fit the container. Check the link in my answer.

Comment: thank you similary i am having problem with customer login how to fix that issue i have given margin on it thats the problem <div class="inner clearfix" style="margin-left: 1000px;">
          <div class="logo">
            <a href="" class="customerLogin">     
             Customer Login
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

Use a default bootstrap's carousel http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel .

Comment: thanks for your reply...can u tell me how to fix the current bug

Comment: thank you similary i am having problem with customer login how to fix that issue i have given margin on it thats the problem <div class="inner clearfix" style="margin-left: 1000px;"> <div class="logo"> <a href="" class="customerLogin"> Customer Login </a> </div> </div>